# Which continuous function satisfies $\int\limits_0^x f(t) dt \ge f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[0,1] $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, indefinite-integrals, integral-inequality

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).
>   Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ be continuous. Suppose
>   $$ \int\limits_0^x f(t) dt \ge f(x), \text{ for all } x \in [0,1]$$
>   Then which of the following is true
>   A. No such function exists
>   B. There are infinitely many such functions
>   C. There is only one such function
>   D. There are exactly two such functions

See the end of the question for correct answer.
I have been able to figure out that, perhaps $e^x$ is one such function so A is NOT the answer.
Correct answer : - C
Source - Tata Institute of Fundamental Research, Graduate School Admissions 2014

Comment: Try the first fundamental theorem of calculus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$e^x$ does not satisfy the condition: try $x=0$.

Hint: if $0 < x < 1$, $$\int_0^x f(t)\; dt \le x \sup_{0 \le t \le x} f(t)$$

Comment: Does $0<x<1$ imply $x * sup \{ f(t) : t \in [0,x] \} $ $\le$ $sup \{ f(t) : t \in [0,x] \}$ and thus, using the inequality you gave, we get $\int_0^x{f(t)} \le sup \{ f(t) : t \in [0,x] \}$ which, since our function is non-negative is only true when the function is zero function?

Answer (score 5):

Given any $f : [0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ continuous which satisfies

$$f(x) \le \int_0^x f(t) dt,\quad \forall x \in [0,1]\tag{*1}$$

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $f$(x) achieves it maximum value $M \ge 0$ somewhere.
We have:

$$\begin{align}
 & f(x) \le M,\quad \forall x \in [0,1]\\
\implies & f(x) \le \int_0^x f(t) dt \le \int_0^x M dt = Mx, \quad\forall x \in [0,1]\\
\implies & f(x) \le \int_0^x f(t) dt \le \int_0^x Mt dt \le M\frac{x^2}{2} \le \frac{M}{2},\quad\forall x \in [0,1]
\end{align}
$$
Since $M$ is the maximum of $f(x)$ over $[0,1]$, the last inequality implies
$$M = \max_{x\in [0,1]} f(x) \le \frac{M}{2}$$
Together with $M \ge 0$, this forces $M = 0$ and hence $f(x)$ is the zero function.

So the answer is $C$. There is only one function, the zero function, which can satisfy $(*1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\, dt$. Then $g'(x) = f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Show that $\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)e^{-x}) \le 0$, and hence $g \le 0$. Since $f \ge 0$, then $g \ge 0$. So $g \equiv 0$, and consequently $f = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant than the other answers, but maybe it will help someone...

---

Following Robert Israel's hint, note
$$f(x) \le \int_0^x f(t)\mathop{dt} \le x \cdot \sup_{0 \le t \le x} f(t)$$
for all $x \in [0,1]$.

---

Hint 2: What happens when you apply the above hint at $x=0$?

For $x=0$, you get $f(0) \le 0$ and thus $f(0)=0$ since $f$ is nonnegative.

---

Hint 3: Can you use the above to conclude that $f =0$ on $[0,1]$?

Suppose $f$ is not identically zero. Then $f(x) > 0 $ for some $x \in (0,1]$. By continuity (intermediate value theorem), we can actually choose $x \in (0,1)$. Then there exists some $c$ such that $x<c<1$.

By continuity, the maximum of $f$ on $[0,c]$ is attained at some $x^* \in [0,c]$, and we have $0<f(x) \le f(x^*)$. But then, applying hint 1 gives
$$f(x^*) \le \int_0^{x^*} f(t) \mathop{dt} \le x^*\cdot \sup_{0 \le t \le x^*} f(t) = x^* \cdot f(x^*) \le c \cdot f(x^*) < f(x^*),$$
a contradiction.